# How to extract data from an XLS file and put it into a 2D array javascript

Tags: javascript

New to Javascript, wondering how I go about extracting data from an excel file and putting it into a 2D array in javascript, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible to convert the excel to a CSV format?

Comment: Yeah I could do that, how could I go about reading the CSV in?

Comment: check this out http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/parsing-local-csv-file-with-javascript-papa-parse/

Answer (score 0):

CSV seems to be a most "programmable" option, but you might get away with creating a column of javascript statements next to your data:

```
| A   | B      | C      | D                                    |
| 123 | abcdef | 999.99 | myArray.push([123,'abcdef',999.99]); |
| 456 | ghijkl | 123.99 | myArray.push([456,'ghijkl',123.99]); |
...
```

So you can just copy/paste the column into the code - good solution if you need a one-off transfer. The formula would be:

```
=concatenate("myArray.push([";A2;",'";B2;"',";C2;"]);")
```

but please check the exact syntax as I've got no English Excel at hand to test.